# How to make OrmLite with CursorLoader efficiently handle batch of changes?

Tags: android, ormlite, android-cursoradapter, android-cursorloader

I am using OrmLite with CursorLoader and CursorAdapter (https://github.com/j256/ormlite-android/pull/8).

One thing I noticed is that, when performing a lot of updates in the database, OrmLiteCursorLoader class receives an onChange callback for each one of those changes, which in turn call onContentChanged() which causes the update of the UI content.
While this works fine for a small number of changes, when performing a lot of changes the UI lags.

I want to know if there is a more efficient way of doing this. Consider the following example:
One table with 800 records, separated into 40 different groups. I am just interested in one group, so I select only this group to be displayed in the UI. However, when I update items in different groups, the onChange callback is called, the UI is updated and this causes an overhead.

My question: Is there a way to know if what has changed in database is being presented in the UI, based on the current selection?

Comment: Try executing your code in here http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_5.html#Batch-Operations

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have enough reputation :/

Comment: I added you a +1 for in case somebody finds this question useful, I cannot vote for myself though